# For-loops are sending my mind into a wild loops and I cant figure out why

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
function main(legacymoney, year2live) {
    let joshAge = 18;
    let yearlyAllowance = 12000;
    let evenyearsLeftover = legacymoney - yearlyAllowance;
    let oddyearsLeftover = evenyearsLeftover - yearlyAllowance - 950;
    evenyearsLeftover = oddyearsLeftover - yearlyAllowance;

    for (let i = 1801; i < year2live; i++) {
        //joshAge++;
        //oddyearsLeftover = evenyearsLeftover -yearlyAllowance-950;

    }
    if (year2live % 2 !== 0) {
        console.log(`He will need ${(oddyearsLeftover-230100).toFixed(2)} dollars to survive.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Yes! He will live a carefree life and will have ${evenyearsLeftover.toFixed(2)} dollars left.`);
    }
}
main(50000,1802);
main(400000,1841);
```

the above code only passed all possible tests because I put a literal 230100 to get the answer because it was failing with the second main(400000,1841); but passing main(50000,1802);
I am getting lost somewhere in the last steps and this for loop is sending me for a loop itself.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! You don't quite explain what your problem really is. Maybe take a look at your question, and try your best to put the information in it that will help someone answer it and help you.

Comment: What you actually want to do?